# Google Cloud Messaging - AUTHENTICATION FAILED

Tags: android, authentication, google-cloud-messaging, cloud, messaging

we have to create an android project with the GCM service for push notifications.
When we try to register to GCM with the GoogleCloudMessaging.register(...) function, it fails and throws an AUTHENTICATION_FAILED exception. We have no idea why.

Here is the google init code we use:

```
private void initGoogleCloudMessaging() {
    // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
    // GCM registration.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String regId = getGoogleCloudMessagingRegistrationID(context);

        if (regId.isEmpty()) {
            registerGoogleCloudMessagingInBackground();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(GCM_TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }
}

private void registerGoogleCloudMessagingInBackground() {
    Log.i("GCM", "Registering..");
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                String regId = gcm.register(Configuration.GoogleCloudMessagingSenderID);
                msg = ">>Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;
                storeGoogleCloudMessagingDeviceID(context, regId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
                Log.e("GCMTest", "GCM: Registration exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                //oldSchoolRegister();
            }
            return msg;
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

We use the correct Projectnumber.

Here is the google part of our XML file:

```
<!-- Permissions necessary for Google's Cloud Messaging Service -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I hope you can help me with that, because it is very frustrating.

Comment: what kind of API key are you using?

Comment: I use an android API Key for the client and a Server API Key for the server

Comment: I also have a Google Account registered on the emulator. And I tried all kinds of solutions, but it doesnt work. It seems like I'm missing something, but I really dont know what

Comment: what do you mean by using Android API key for client? and another key for server?

Comment: I mean I created an API Key for an android client on the Google Cloud Messaging site(with the default.keystore file) and I've created a server key for our server aswell. I also activated the Cloud Messaging API and the Google Maps API for my app.

Comment: Update: it just doesnt work with the emulator. But I really dont know why. I installed the Google Play package

Comment: Did you know that you only need one key when setting up GCM in your applications. And that key is SERVER key. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and this [tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-23-getting-started-with-gcm-android-push-notifications-and-pubnub/) for more information.

Comment: WEll, we've learned it with the android client API key. Doesn't that make more sense for a client? It works with that btw. Just not with the emulator.